# No output when executing the script python 3.8.5 VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I´m developing a simple reactive programming script example to download images from a web, but when I execute the script in **VScode** I do not get any type of output, I already tried creating a **VirtualEnv**

In the terminal i get this output:

> PS C:\Users\ernes\Desktop\paradigmas> &
> C:/Users/ernes/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe
> c:/Users/ernes/Desktop/paradigmas/jose.py PS
> C:\Users\ernes\Desktop\paradigmas>

## CODE:

```
import base64
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import io
import rx
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class App:
    
    async def getSourceCode(url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as clientSession:
            serverResponse = await clientSession.get(url)
            sourceCode = await serverResponse.text()
            return sourceCode     
    
    async def main(self, urlToProcess='https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/38M_Toldi'):
        print(urlToProcess)
        sourceCode = self.getSourceCode(urlToProcess)
        parsedSource = BeautifulSoup(sourceCode, 'html.parser')
        for imgItem in parsedSource.find_all('img', src=True):
            if imgItem['src'].find('http') == True:
                imgSrc = imgItem['src']
                if len(imgItem['alt']) > 0 :
                    imgName = imgItem['alt']
                else:
                    imgName = imgSrc
            if not imgName in self.imgs:
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as clientSession:
                    try:
                        serverResponse = await clientSession.get(imgSrc)
                        imgBytes = await serverResponse.read(serverResponse)

                        if imgBytes:
                            self.bytesfoto.append(imgBytes)
                            print(f'{imgName} : {imgSrc}')

                    except:

                        print('Error al descargar la foto')
    """
    Definicion de los atributos de la clase iniciales donde se guardan los datos que se usaran en el tkinter para la GUI

    contador -- es el que lleva la cuenta de la cantidad de imágenes que se añaden a la lista
    window -- define la ventana de la GUI
    imgs -- lista en la que se guardan las URLs de las imágenes
    bytesfoto -- lista en la que se guardan las fotos en bytes para poder guardarlas en memoria
    objImg -- variable que convierte los links de las fotos en observables

    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.contador = 0
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title = "Reactive-Programming"
        self.imgs = []
        self.bytesfoto = []
        self.objImg = rx.from_iterable(self.imgs)
```

Comment: I think this needs ´App().main()´ at the end of the file because you have although defined a class, but havent called it.

Comment: @BijayRegmi tried it but isn´t working althought

Comment: Seems like a code issue, not vscode, its weird imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the bottom, outside of the class

```
theobj = asyncio.run(App().main())
theobj()
```

The script should work after, with some errors.